# Docker exec bash interactively small terminal window

Tags: docker, tty

Suppose I have container that run `bash` interactively with one of the following way:

- `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash`.
- `docker start <stopped_container>` and then `docker attach <container>`.

When I want another interactively session I do the next command: `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash`. All seems to be fine but the terminal window is small:

[image]

How can I expand new interactively `bash` terminal session to desired size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using [`stty`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) program that changes and prints terminal line settings.

Suppose I want to get equal terminal sizes for `bash` session which I started with `docker run -it ...` or `docker attach ...` and `bash` session which I started with `bash exec -it`.

Firstly I I should get current terminal size for the first terminal:

```
bash-4.2# stty size
68 317
```

The I should set equal values for the second terminal:

```
bash-4.2# stty size # check current terminal size before (it's not required)
0 0
bash-4.2# stty rows 68
bash-4.2# stty cols 317
```

Now, the terminal size is equal for both terminals:
[image]